# locale is not valid while it is clearly present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to implement locales in an early stage of my build but i get the following error:

```
I18n::InvalidLocale
:nl is not a valid locale
```

Yet, `I18n.available_locales` returns `[ :en, :nl ]`

This error is thrown by

```
el_nl = t el, :locale => :nl
```

`el` being the argument passed on to the function.

How can I make `:nl` a valid locale if it's already present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out I didn't restart my server after inserting another locale. restarting the server did the trick for me.

(I feel like I could as well have forgotten to plugin my PC).